# Click elements on Zomato using Python Selenium Chrome Driver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to gather all the submission time of reviews from Zomato. Not the ones from the "Popular" tab but the ones from the "All Reviews" tab.

For me to do that I have to click the "All Reviews" tab but I am having a hard time doing it and my code keeps on printing the ones from the "Popular" tab.

Output:

- 21 days ago
- one month ago
- one month ago
- 2 months ago
- 2 months ago
- 2 months ago

Expected Output:

- yesterday
- 4 days ago
- 4 days ago
- 13 days ago
- 14 days ago

Note: Output shows result of the code from the day this question was posted.

["Review Tabs"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyXwV.jpg)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

chromeDriver = "....\\chromedriver"
URL = "https://www.zomato.com/cebu/the-pyramid-lahug-cebu-city"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromeDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriver)
driver.get(URL)

driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-sort='reviews-dd']")[0].click()

timeList = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('time')
for time in timeList:
    print(time.text)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: You should post a minimal example that can easily be reproduced by every one. That helps a lot to understand quickly your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this piece of code may be it work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser=webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get("https://www.zomato.com/cebu/the-pyramid-lahug-cebu-city")
delay=15
#browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight/2)")
time.sleep(2)

element = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//*[@id='selectors']/a[2]")))
element.click()
element = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".item.default-section-title.everyone.empty")))
element.click()
print "click done"
time= WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".grey-text>time")))
for i in time:
    print i.text
browser.quit()
```

Comment: The reason behind you output is that your page is not scrolled.